# C&P Certain Cells from Mutliple Workbooks into 1 File

Tags: vba

I have a folder of 74 excel survey results, where I have to pull four data points from each and all are in different parts of the file (i.e. D12, D12, E78 and F93). Might be a simple fix but how can I paste the subsequent file's data below the previous file's data. When I do this now I think I am just getting the last file's data points. I have only tried out my iteration on a test folder with 2 data files, as opposed to all 74.

```
Sub SurveyRecordsAggregator()

Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
   MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
   Err.Clear
End With

'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and statsu bar updates to help code run faster
'you'll be opening and closing many files so this will prevent your screen from displaying that

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder you selected
'and then close that file before opening the next file

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

Do While MyFile <> ""
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo 0
    Workbooks.Open filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False
    
    Worksheets("Fund").Range("D12").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Fund").Range("D23").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Fund").Range("E78").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Fund").Range("F93").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    MsgBox MyFile
0
    Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    MyFile = Dir
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
Loop

'turns settings back on that you turned off before looping folders

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good case for using Power Query

Comment: You currently have the paste destination hardcoded to `A3:D3`. One option is to use a variable that holds the numeric portion of the range. For example `i = 3`, then your paste line would read: `Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` (do the same for the other lines). Finally, just before the `Loop` call, increment the variable i, such as `i = i + 1`. Does this help?